# EditText loses its borders after failure in submission

Tags: android, android-edittext

I built a screen that looks like this:

[image]

but if login fails the screen turns out to look like this:

[image]

I used `EditText` and the code looks like this:

```
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:text="email"></TextView>  
        <EditText 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:hint=""
            android:textStyle="normal"
    android:singleLine="true" 
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress">                
        </EditText>  
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:text="password">
        </TextView>  
        <EditText 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/uc_txt_password" 
            android:hint=""
            android:textStyle="normal"
    android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textPassword">
        </EditText>
```

Any ideas?

**Update:**
It seems that the bogus display is the way it displays on Ice-cream-sandwich by default. I am using an older version of android (2.2) on which the display looks like the first attached pic.

Comment: @Vivek please be more careful when you edit, you have removed the images.

Comment: Oh I am so sorry.I didn't notice that.Thanks a lot for that@Shadow Wizard

Comment: Are these the default edittext backgrounds?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - what do you mean ? can you be more specific ?

Comment: alfasin I wasn't talking to you, sorry.. Vivek edited your post to fix some grammar mistakes and removed the images added by Adil in previous edit. @Vivek - the `@` must have space before so your notification didn't go through, saw it only now.

Comment: can you please add your activity code?

Comment: it's too much code to add in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICS Introduces a more "open" text layout (look at the gmail app) where edit text's default style lack borders. You should more rigidly define your style to be how you want it on all devices if you don't want it to look like how the device sets it. Perhaps use some 9 patch images and state selector xml files. So if you're setting the background to something like white and not defining any other styles it might be inheriting from Holo.Dark and using this as the edit text bg: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/textfield_default_holo_dark.9.png

Thus, no visible text. Define your style more rigidly, or set your themes better and don't override the other backgrounds.

Comment: I know that I'll need to find a better solution for ICS (said that in the update) - thanks for the link though.

Comment: Not sure why you put up a bounty... if you just get a good background 9-patch and define your style your issue is solved on all of the current API Levels. You could even go steal the 9 patch from the resources in the GB Branch if you wanted.

Comment: @Sleepybar what is GB Branch ? GitHub ? and you're right, but I'm not sure how to remove the bounty, maybe I should just award it to you... :) but seriously, I would rather find the bug and fix it then go for a workaround.

Comment: The bug to fix is you setting the background to white instead of using the complete OS/Rom Theme. GB Branch is Gingerbread branch, you can access it on github. Look in frameworks_base/core/res/res for the resources they use. You could also just supply your own drawable (probably a 9 patch) for the background.

Comment: Thanks! since ICS behaves different from Gingerbread - Do you think that I should change the display according to OS ?

Comment: It's not so much behaves differently as is themed differently. ICS Intentionally leaves borders off of `EditText`s. You should either provide your own drawable resource, or fix your layout to be compatible for both OS styles. (As I've repeatedly mentioned)

Comment: I know I didn't post the following additional "minor" detail: but not only the borders disappeared on ICS (for which you provided a good explanation) - but also the "submit" button stopped working. I was hoping that the problems are related but now I'm not so sure anymore. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try to use android selector

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/editbox_dropdown_background"  android:state_focused="false"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/editbox_background_focus_yellow"  android:state_focused="true"/>
  />
</selector>
```